# Is it possible using CSS to create a grid image or error image in IE?

Tags: css, html, internet-explorer

The picture is just like the following...

Is it possible to draw a image like that with CSS in the internet explorer ??

I try to use filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient. But it doesn't work at all

[image: Error image]

[image: Harsh image]

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Use for example [`canvas`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API).

Comment: canvas will need some javascript to fullfill this image... Can we just use css to handle this problem ?

Comment: `canvas` doesn't need JS, though you can use CSS `transform` too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### SVG

The svg tag is supported by IE9 and above (see [here](http://caniuse.com/#search=svg)). A simple cross can be drawn with two paths like [this (jsFiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/Lnnm0z8t/).

### VML

If you want to support IE versions before IE9, you can use the VML. This is *exclusive* to Internet Explorer, though. I currently dont have access to Internet Explorer, but a cross should look something like this:

```
<!-- Include the VML behavior -->
<style>v\: * { behavior:url(#default#VML); display:inline-block }</style>

<!-- Declare the VML namespace -->
<xml:namespace ns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" prefix="v" />

<v:line style='position:absolute;' from="0pt,0pt" to="200pt,200pt" strokecolor="red" strokeweight="2pt"><v:stroke dashstyle="solid" /></v:line>
<v:line style='position:absolute;' from="200pt,0pt" to="0pt,200pt" strokecolor="red" strokeweight="2pt"><v:stroke dashstyle="solid" /></v:line>
```